# WPF Customcontrol based on DataGrid + Custom Events

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid, custom-controls

I'm currently writing a Customcontrol based on the standard WPF Datagrid. I've implemented a toolbar with some functions like sorting, grouping and filtering. With an ICollectionView as ItemsSource these functions are fairly easy to implement.

My problem lies within the events the toolbar buttons should fire:
I've managed to raise the buttonclick events to my codebehind for the view (MyDataGrid.cs) via Commands (SortClick, GroupClick, FilterClick).

```
                                    <ToolBarTray Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" IsLocked="True">
                                        <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1" >
                                            <Button Width="24" Height="24" ToolTip="Sort" Command="{x:Static local:PDataGrid.SortClick}">
                                                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/PControls;component/Resources/sort.png" />
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button Width="24" Height="24" ToolTip="Filter" Command="{x:Static local:PDataGrid.GroupClick}">
                                                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/PControls;component/Resources/filter.png" />
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button Width="24" Height="24" ToolTip="Group" Command="{x:Static local:PDataGrid.FilterClick}">
                                                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/PControls;component/Resources/group.png" />
                                            </Button>
                                        </ToolBar>
                                    </ToolBarTray>
```

But how do I raise these events out of my view, so that any class working with my control (in my case MyDataGridView.cs) can handle them?

My ICommands are defined as static (as I saw it in some examples).
RaiseEvent which I would use to raise a RoutedEvent which my viewmodel could catch is non-static.

```
    public static readonly RoutedEvent SortClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("SClick", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(PDataGrid));

    public event RoutedEventHandler SClick
    {
        add { AddHandler(SortClickEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(SortClickEvent, value); }
    }

    private void raiseSortClickEvent()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs e = new RoutedEventArgs(PDataGrid.SortClickEvent);
        RaiseEvent(e);
    }

    private static ICommand sortClick;
    public static ICommand SortClick
    {
        get
        {
            if (sortClick == null)
            {
                sortClick = new BaseCommand(sort);
            }

            return sortClick;
        }
        set { sortClick = value; }
    }

    private static void sort()
    {
        // sort() = static, therefore not working...
        //raiseSortClickEvent();
    }
```

Please help - maybe there is a much simpler solution which I can't see at the moment...

---

Oh I forgot to mention that I'm developing my control under MVVM pattern and would like to stick with it. The whole logic (filter, group, sort) should be in my viewmodel.

Edit:
Oh I forgot to mention that I'm developing my control under MVVM pattern and would like to stick with it. The whole logic (filter, group, sort) should be in my viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand. What stops you from binding button commands into viewmodel and do the magic in viewmodel? (such as CollectionView sort etc..). Usually you bind against DataContext&viewmodel directly. No code behind involved.

Comment: Hm, it's hard for me to explain it - my english is a bit rusty - but i'll try. On one side I've got a CustomDataGrid with Buttons added to it = 'Control-View'. On the other side there is my MainWindow = View, which is bound to a ViewModel. My understandig is, that I'll need to put all the logic for filtering, sorting and grouping in my Control-View.

Comment: But this 'Control-View' has no access to the ItemSource, which is in the ViewModel for my MainWindow. I hope my problem is clearer now - if not don't hesitate to ask! I would appreciate any help

Comment: <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.SortClick}" />

now in your ViewModel, implement SortClick command and there, implement logic, like this:  YourCollection.Sort();

This is, assuming your control is part of the visual tree & MainWindow.

Comment: With this I would have to do all the logic, which belongs into my CustomDataGrid, outside of it. Everyone who uses the control would have to deal not only with ICollectionView.Sort and so on, but would also need to write a window for each function to configure it (e.g. window for sort-config consists of a datagrid where you can choose columns and sort-directions). So unfortunately throwing events out to the ViewModel of my MainWindow does not help me. :/

Comment: Add SortClickCommand into CustomDataGri. Now add new event handler into the CustomDataGrid.cs, such as SortButtonClicked, and in there, do  SortClickCommand.Execute(). This let's everyone override the functionality of SortClickCommand as they wish. 
<CustomDataGrid SortClickCommand="{Binding randomBindingToSomePlace}" />

Comment: I think you misunderstood. Sorting should be a built in functionality in my control. I don't want anybody to override it. The function, the toolbar and the settings-window are worked into the control and are available without overriding anything. To accomplish this everything (logic and UI) have to be in my CustomDataGrid. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: I am still unsure about this: "Control-View" has no access to the ItemsSource.

Why does it have no access? 
You're suppose to have XAML element declared as:
<CustomDataGrid 
  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.ItemsSource}" />
You can access ItemsSource in Control-View by referencing against "ItemsSource" property of DataGrid directly. Everyone can provide their own itemsource(from viewmodel, from codebehind, from whatever source they want). You would have to take care of different collections though.

Comment: Ok, that was my fault - "Control-View" has access to the ItemsSource. My only problem left is that the Command for the SortButton has to be static and so I cannot access a specific ItemsSource... Command="{x:Static local:MyDataGrid.SortClick}"

Comment: When I try to use the Click-Event I get an error at compile time stating that I must use an "x:Class" attribute for the root "ResourceDictionary". If I give it a class name I get another error: "Click={Binding SortClick} is invalid. It is no valid methodname for the eventhandler. Only instance methods for the generated or codebehind class are valid." But SortClick is definately a public and non-static method in my Control-View...